# Filter data using max value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model consists of order field , I want to fetch that row who have max value for `order`.

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   order = models.IntegerField()
```

Now let say I want to fetch records for user 1 , for this user total no of rows exist in table are `10` but I want only that row who have max order value.

Also If I wanted to fetch records for two users then same condition must be applied. For this filter query must return one row for every user with max value for `order` col.

right I am using annotate but it returns all rows

```
rows = MyModel.objects.annotate(max_seq=Max('order')).filter(user = 1)
```

so when I loop over this rows it print all 10 rows , but it must return only one row with col max order value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put users (which you wanted to filter records of) in list and then iterate through them and fire a query what stellasia suggested..

```
users = [1,2,3]

for user in users:
   row = MyModel.objects.filter(user__id = user).order_by("order")[0]
```

Here it will give the result you wanted even if there is only one user in users list..

Comment: I was already looping over array , but got one thing wrong in my logic so thats why it was not working , anyway thx a lot for your hepl

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) and take only the first returned element :

```
rows = MyModel.objects.filter(user = 1).order_by("orders")[0]
```

**Following comment**, this solution will not work to get the max for all users. I would do it the other way around, starting from the User model :

```
users = User.objects.annotate(Max("mymodel__order"))
print users[0].mymodel__order__max
```

see also [this part of the django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Comment: But using limit don't it be failed for multiple users , If I am fetching data for more then one user, then it will return only one row and for only one user, I want row for all users but with max order value

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad, I skipped this part of the question :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem using only Django ORM.

Example data:

```
MyModel.objects.values('user__id', 'order')
[{'user__id': 1, 'order': 1}, {'user__id': 1, 'order': 2}, {'user__id': 2, 'order': 1}, {'user__id': 2, 'order': 2}, {'user__id': 2, 'order': 3}]
```

and the query:

```
MyModel.objects.values("user").annotate(ordermax=Max("order")).order_by()
[{'ordermax': 2, 'user': 1}, {'ordermax': 3, 'user': 2}]
```

Django doc reference: [Interaction with default ordering or order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)